# ImportError: cannot import name 'MutualTLSChannelError' from 'google.auth.exceptions'

Tags: google-api-python-client, python-3.10

Trying to import the Earth Engine Library

```
import ee

# Initialize the Earth Engine library
ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()
```

On the very first line I am getting an Import Error.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [12], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import ee
      3 # Initialize the Earth Engine library
      4 ee.Authenticate()
   .
   .
   .

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py:43, in <module>
     40 import urllib
     42 import google.api_core.client_options
---> 43 from google.auth.exceptions import MutualTLSChannelError
     44 from google.auth.transport import mtls
     45 from google.oauth2 import service_account
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'MutualTLSChannelError' from
> 'google.auth.exceptions'
> (C:\Users\marat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\auth\exceptions.py)

I checked at the specified location and the class 'MutualTLSChannelError' is available.
Also tried upgrading all the packages. Does not help.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because for some reaosn the google-auth installed on my env was 1.4.2 whereas it should be 2.26.1. Running `pip install --upgrade google-auth` solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with 'google.auth.exceptions' because of name pollution.  It was giving me module not found error.  I wasn't using Earth Engine Library but [youtube-uploader](https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload).
The uploader needed google-api-python-client.  I installed it in an environment.  When I got the error I tried to manually import in ipython for testing.  Even though ipython was able to find it, say, google.auth.exceptions when I use table completion, the moment I say `from google.auth.exceptions import *` it threw error.
I was able to do `import google`.  When I searched inside the environment directory I found that I have multiple *google* modules.  One was from google-api-python-client and another from googleapis-common-protos.  I am not sure where it came from, but the two 'googles' where creating trouble.
So I uninstalled the latter using pip.  And wow, my uploader start working.